# reactjs create-react-app missing index.html in src folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `create-react-app` command to create an empty app, I got these file in `src` folder:

```
App.css
App.js
App.test.js
index.css
index.js
logo.svg
serviceWorker.js
setupTests.js
```

After I make a build via `npm run build`, `index.html` is generated in `build` folder.

I created one manually in `src` folder, but the build doesn't take it.

The `index.js` content is:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

There is no `root` element at all.

I need to add in some `<script>` tag inside `index.html` to include some third party scripts (which cannot be installed by nodejs), where can I add them since it is not existed in `src` folder?

Comment: It's usually under `public` folder

Comment: @MorKadosh you are right! really out of expectation...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to check public folder in the root directory only. You will get your index.html would be there. and your index.js file which is in src folder is the single point of connection between them(main index.html in public folder and all Javascript code which is in src folder).
[image]

Comment: You are right, my bad, thought everything is in `src` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should download that third party lybrairie and put it inside of the public directory and include a `script` tag inside of the `index.html` file which is inside of the `public` directory of your project.

The configuration of the `create-react-app` is using webpack which is preconfigure to load the `public\index.html` file as the template in which the compiled bundle will be injected.

If you want to use the `index.html` file which you have create inside of the `src` folder you should run `npm run eject` which will put all create-react-app configuration at your disposal in your project directory and you could perform changes to webpack figuration file to load `src/index.html` file as the template in which the compiled bundle will be injected.